# I have tried to install the LinConnectServer on my Ubuntu 13.10 and I cant install it

Tags: android

I have tried installing the LinCOnnectserver on my ubuntu 13.10 and it failed to install. I have tried it in two ways. The first method is by using the direct commands given in the https://github.com/hauckwill/linconnect-server/ github page. The second method i tried is that i have downloaded the zip file and extracted it.I have run the install.sh file in the terminal but i couldnt succeed in the installation.
moreover i went in to the main directory and i have run the linconnect.py file but itis also of no use. Please help

Comment: Same problem noted at http://askubuntu.com/questions/562339/linconnect-failure-to-install